# Spring Controller Mapping value regex

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring controller method

```
@GetMapping(value = {"{name}"})
public String index(ModelMap model, @PathVariable Optional<String> name)
```

I would like everything to go through this method except anything that contains a period. So something like `/main.css` will be rejected while something like `/maincss` will be allowed. Is there any way I can do that?

I understand that I can simply move all my resources file to resources path like `/resources/main.css` and the problem is fixed, or I can change up the code so that I have two methods, one for `/` and one for `/name/{name}`. But for educational purposes I was wondering if I can have controller apply to everything except a certain regex. Like for example what if I want the controller to accept everything except a string that contains a word Norris.

Is there anyway to apply regex or some sort of rules to mapping value?

Comment: You can apply interceptor logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format `varName:regex` (where colon ":" is the separator between the two) to indicate a regex check to be used on the variable:

```java
@GetMapping(value = {"{name:^((?!Norris).)*$}"})
public String index(ModelMap model, @PathVariable Optional<String> name)
```

However, since your problem might be related to resources:

> I understand that I can simply move all my resources file to resources path like /resources/main.css

You could also try to configure a [`ResourceHandlerRegistry`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html) or a [`ResourceResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceResolver.html) to exclude certain file (patterns) from being served as resources. More info regarding resource handling can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

Comment: Perfect!!! Sorry resources was just one of the examples for me really. My main point was how to apply regex to the mapping value as title suggested and I just used resources as what I thought a valid example. Your answer helped me with everything and blew me out of the water!!! Love it! Thanks :)